# How can we play Windows mms stream in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flexbuilder

I'm developing a Flex app (Flash Builder 4.5 AIR app). Flex can play other streams but it does not supports mms://url stream. can anyone suggest some sort of codec library in actionscript/flex. I want to design a stream radio app for desktop. Please help

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no such codecs are available,! one approach is to live encode (using http://www.ffmpeg.org/ etc) the mms stream into an mp3 and use Flex to play the streaming mp3.